# Java poi: how to add a table in a HSSFCell

Tags: java, apache-poi

i am trying to add a table 
|test1 |test 2|
                           ---------------
                           |25%   |78%   | 
in a HSSFCell in java. 
Can you please provide some example code for the same?

Comment: Most people do it the other way round, they add cells to tables.

Comment: you want to add table in one cell, right ?

Comment: @yogesh yes i want to add table in one cell

Comment: how would you add Table in cell?. in ms excel or openoffice calc. is that possible manually ? is yes than i'll do. but provide steps that show how to add table in cell manually.

Comment: I can not add manually a table in a cell on excel. i can do it only in world. i contune to search if it is possible manually